# enqueueWriteBuffer locking up when sending non-32 bit aligned data

Tags: opencl

I am working on an opencl project and I have run into an issue where if I try and send data to from the cpu to global memory then sometimes it locks up the application. This happens sporadically. I can run it x times in a row and the next time it locks. It only appears to be happening if I try and send data that is not 32 bits wide. For example, I can send float and int just fine, but when I try short, char, or half then I get random lockups. It is not dying with badly initialized data or something, because it does run, just not all the time. I also put some logging in and found that it is always locking up just after attempting to write one of these non-standard size data arrays. I am running on an NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M. Below is a snippet of the code I am running to send the data. I am using the c++ interface on the host side.

```
cl_half *m_aryTest;

shared_ptr< cl::Buffer > m_bufTest;

m_aryTest = new cl_half[m_iNeuronCount];

m_bufTest = shared_ptr<cl::Buffer>( new cl::Buffer(m_lpNervousSystem->ActiveContext(), CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(m_aryTest)*m_iNeuronCount, m_aryTest));


kernel.setArg(8, *(m_bufTest.get()));


printf("m_bufTest.\n");

m_lpQueue->enqueueWriteBuffer(*(m_bufTest.get()), CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(m_aryTest)*m_iNeuronCount,  m_aryTest, NULL, NULL);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: This may be a bug in the Cuda framework. To be sure, try to reproduce this behavior with a minimal program and submit it on the official bug reporting tool or forum.

Comment: "sizeof(m_aryTest)" You probably want to make that "sizeof(*m_aryTest)" or "sizeof(cl_half)"! You're looking up the pointer's size here, which is a buffer overflow since it's bigger than a half. May not be the cause of your issue, but you should fix it anyway.